# Positioning text before the number generated by an ordered list

Tags: html, css, sass, html-lists

I am working on a progress steps widget, and trying to use an `<ol>` to number each step. Right now, it shows up as `1 step`, which is the default behavior. Does anyone know how I can position the text so that it shows up like `step 1`? Please see my [example](http://codepen.io/obliviga/pen/bwGgxV) on Codepen for more information. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `&:before` into `&:after`

```css
.progress-step-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.progress-step-container:first-child {
  counter-reset: customlistcounter;
}
.progress-step-container .step {
  display: inline;
  max-width: 108px;
  width: 108px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  counter-increment: customlistcounter;
}
.progress-step-container .step.current {
  border-bottom: 6px solid #1578CD;
  max-width: 442px;
  width: 442px;
}
.progress-step-container .step:after {
  content: counter(customlistcounter);
}
```

```html
<ol class="progress-step-container">
  <li class="step step-1">
    <span class="step-message"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="step step-2 current">
    <span class="step-message">Question</span>
  </li>
</ol>
```